# How to get the validation message under the input field using WFFM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Sitecore in combination with Webforms For Marketers (WFFM). The error messages are showed at the top of the page now. I want to display the error messages under the input fields.

Does anyone know how i could realize this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem a year ago. And the answer on this [blog post](http://petersondave.wordpress.com/tag/web-forms-for-marketers/) solved my problem.

I showed them labels but as you want it gives the answer.

Comment: Thank you, skzac. Where must I make this code changes? Could you explain it some? Must I create for all fields custom validators?

Comment: Not Really. I use classes to do so with some reference. Can you please  show me some code here so that I can solve your problem easily. Thank you.